# Multiple UILabel in single row

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, concatenation, axis-labels

[image]

Need help to create a UILables layout like this with multiple Labels an multiple actions. Consider the Facebook News&Feed example for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) and `NSAttributedString` to do that. Don't use multiple `UILabel` instances :). [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) allows you to add actions for any parts of your string.